# Floating action button is jump, when click on it

Tags: java, android, xml

When I click on FAB to show Snackbar, Fab is jump and Snackbar hided Fab
[image]

[image]

My code

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:id="@+id/main_coordinator_layout">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/bottom_app_bar"
        app:fabAlignmentMode="center"
        android:layout_width = match_parent
        android:layout_height = wrap_content
        android:layout_gravity = bottom
        android:backgroundTint" = @color/colorPrimary
        fabCradleMargin" = 15dp
        fabCradleRoundedCornerRadius = 15dp
        hideOnScroll = true
        layout_scrollFlags = scroll|enterAlways
        buttonGravity = bottom
        app:menu="@menu/menu"/>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_plus"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/bottom_app_bar"
        android:layout_width = wrap_content
        android:layout_height = wrap_content
        android:backgroundTint = "@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I tried change params view on snackbar, but it do not work

```
public void showSnackBar(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, FloatingActionButton fab, String text) {

    Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayout, text, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
    View snackBarView = snackbar.getView();
    CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) snackBarView.getLayoutParams();
    params.setMargins(
            params.leftMargin,
            params.topMargin,
            params.rightMargin,
            params.bottomMargin + 100);
    snackBarView.setLayoutParams(params);
    snackbar.setAnchorView(fab);
    snackbar.show();

}
```

How can I fix it ?  so that FAB does not jump or Snackbar showed up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you are using `CoordinatorLayout` `FAB` will always move up when `snackbar` shows up  .

> The CoordinatorLayout can listen to all it’s direct child view’s
>   event, and when some event occured such as snackbar popup, it will
>   move the floating button up also.

so it's a natural behavior , so to avoid that you should create a custom behavior.
So, how do you customize this behavior? You define your own Behavior subclass , please read [this](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/customizing-coordinatorlayouts-behavior/) tutorial for more info  .

Comment: when I change coordinator layout to relative or linear, shown error This BottomAppBar must be wrapped in a CoordinatorLayout

Comment: sorry , please check my edit ! , hope it will help you

Comment: i tried code from tutorial and my FAB hided, when snackbar show))) and show Fab when snackbar hided

Comment: yes it was an example , so you have to create yours and do nothing in your onDependentViewChanged